# How to deal with error in Cox analysis with R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, survival-analysis

I have been trying to perform a COX analysis with data from GEO:

```
#loading data from GEO
gset <- getGEO('GSE17536', GSEMatrix =TRUE, getGPL=FALSE) 
x<-exprs(gset[[1]]) 

#removing Affymetrix control probes 
x<-x[-grep('^AFFX', rownames(x)),] 

#transforming expression data to Z scores 
x<-t(scale(t(x)))

# extract information of interest from the phenotype data (pdata)
idx<-which(colnames(pData(gset[[1]])) %in% c('age:ch1', 'ajcc_stage:ch1', 'dfs_event (disease free survival; cancer recurrence):ch1', 'dfs_time:ch1', 'gender:ch1', 'overall survival follow-up time:ch1', 'overall_event (death from any cause):ch1'))
metadata<-data.frame(pData(gset[[1]])[,idx],row.names=rownames(pData(gset[[1]])))

#removing samples with NA values----
discard<-apply(metadata,1,function(x) any(is.na(x))) 
metadata<-metadata[!discard,] 

#filter the Z-scores expression data to match the samples in our data 
x<-x[,which(colnames(x) %in% rownames(metadata))] 

#checking that sample names match exactly bewteen pdata and Z-scores 
all((colnames(x)==rownames(metadata))==TRUE) 

#converting data to 0/1
metadata[1][metadata[1]=="recurrence"] <- 1
metadata[1][metadata[1]=="no recurrence"] <- 0

#creating merged data and Z-scores 
coxdata<-data.frame(metadata,t(x)) 

#tidying column names 
colnames(coxdata)[1:7]<-c('Age', 'Ajcc_stage', 'dfs_event', 'dfs_time', 'Gender', 'OverallSurvival_time', 'Overall_event')

#preparing phenotypes 
coxdata$dfs_event<-as.numeric(coxdata$dfs_event)
coxdata$dfs_time<-as.numeric(coxdata$dfs_time)
coxdata$OverallSurvival_time<-as.numeric(coxdata$OverallSurvival_time)
coxdata$Overall_event<-as.numeric(coxdata$Overall_event)

#testing each gene with the data (RFS first)
Res1<-RegParallel(data=coxdata,formula='Surv(dfs_time, dfs_event)~[*]',FUN=function(formula,data) coxph(formula=formula, data=data, ties='breslow',singular.ok=TRUE), FUNtype='coxph', variables=colnames(coxdata)[8:ncol(coxdata)],blocksize = 2000, cores=2,nestedParallel=FALSE, conflevel=95)
```

But I keep getting

```
index1: 54001; index2: 54613
Error in { : task 1 failed - "No (non-missing) observations"
```

after the RegParallel command. Can anyone tell me why please?
P. S: the dataset recorded dfs_event as 'recurrence' and 'no recurrence' and Overall_event as 'death' and 'no death'

Comment: Need `library` calls to load necessary packages. Also need a small portion of that dataset. Appears to me that it is huge (1.5 Gb). Also, if you don't get a response here with this "no data attached" question after a day or two, consider resubmitting to the BioConductor help mailing list. You might get lucky with someone who already has that dataset in their workspace.

Comment: From the error you're getting, check the type of `dfs_time` and `dfs_event`. One thing you can do to make it minimally reproducible is post the result of `dput(head(cox_data, 50))` here.